# How can I resolve this void issue and fix all my code? I'm using python .cs to fix the script for it to run in unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class VideoManager : MonoBehaviour
{
    private VideoPlayer videoPlayer;

    private void Start()
    {
        videoPlayer = GetComponent <VideoPlayer> ();
    }

    public void Play()
    {
        videoPlayer.Play();
    }

    public void Pause()
    {
        videoPlayer.Pause();
    }

    public void Stop()
    {
        videoPlayer.Stop();
    }

    public void URLToVideo(string.Url)
    {
        videoPlayer.source = VideoSource.Url;
        videoPlayer.url = url;
        videoPLayer.Prepare();
        videoPlayer.prepareCompleted +=VideoPlayer)prepare Completed;
    }

    private void VideoPlayer)prepareCompleted(VideoPlayer source)
    {
        Play;
    }
}
```

this was shown when i try to run the code.

> '::', , , , , , , , , , CsTokenType.., CsTokenType.<, CsTokenType.class, CsTokenType.const, CsTokenType.delegate, CsTokenType.enum, CsTokenType.event, CsTokenType.identifier_or_keyword, CsTokenType.interface, CsTokenType.struct or partial expected, got 'void'

Comment: This looks like C# but I'm not sure. Did you write it?

Comment: I didn't write it

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly **how** you are trying to run this code and where.

This is a Unity component that needs to be attached to a `GameObject` within a scene in the Unity Editor. **It makes no sense** at all to run this code in a different way as it uses certain types and libraries that only the Unity framework provides.

---

And then there are a couple of typos:

1. The parameter in

   ```
   public void URLToVideo(string.Url)
   ```

   should most probably rather be

   ```
   public void URLToVideo(string url)
   ```
2. The name

   ```
   VideoPlayer)prepareCompleted
   ```

   is **not** a valid method name. It should probably rather have been e.g.

   ```
   private void VideoPlayerPrepareCompleted(VideoPlayer source)
   ```
3. You have spaces where you attach the listener. It should be (according to method name above)

   ```
   videoPlayer.prepareCompleted += VideoPlayerPrepareCompleted;
   ```
4. Finally as mentioned I would rather attach listeners before calling the method. Otherwise if for some reason it finishes right away you don't get the callback

   ```
   videoPlayer.prepareCompleted += VideoPlayerPrepareCompleted;
   videoPLayer.Prepare();
   ```